# Query for at least one key (of a list) in embedded document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents like this in one collection (let's call `x`) at MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : ...,
    "attrs" : {
        "A2" : {
            "type" : "typeA",
            "value" : "12.2"
        },
        "A3" : {
            "type" : "typeB",
            "value" : "34"
        }
    }
}
```

In other words, they are documents with an `attr` field which value is an embedded document which an arbitrary number of keys (in the example A2 and A3 keys are shown).

Given a list of potential keys (e.g. A1, A2, A3) I would like a query to get all document which have *at least one* of the keys in the given list. My first idea was to use:

```
db.x.find({"attrs": {$in:[ "A1", "A2", "A3" ]})
```

but it doesn't work.

I have found a query that solves the problem in the following way:

```
db.x.find({$or: [ {"attrs.A1": {$exists: true }}, 
                  {"attrs.A2": {$exists: true }}, 
                  {"attrs.A3": {$exists: true }} ] })
```

However, I wonder if there is a better and more "compact" solution, like the first find() example that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something inverse about what you want. If you want to get `attrs` which have at least one key in it, you can use `$ne` of mongo like-

```
db.collection.find({"attrs":{$ne:{}}})
```

By checking if `attrs` is empty or not you can get desired result.
Hope this will useful to you.

Comment: Not exactly... what I want is to get all the documents which have at least one of the keys in *the given list* (in the example of the post that list is: A1, A2 and A3). I mean, not the documents that has at least one *whatever* key. I have edited the post to make it clearer. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator and the [**`Array.prototype.some()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

```js
db.collection.find({ $where: function(){ 
        return Object.keys(this.attrs).some(function(elt){ 
            return ( ["A1", "A2", "A3"].indexOf(elt) != -1 ); }) 
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for you feedback! That query will solve the problem, however the usage of $where is discouraged (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/: "you should use $where only when you can’t express your query using another operator")

Comment: @fgalan I am aware of the use of `$where` operator. :) Now what if you want to check the `attrs` field against an array of thousand elements you received from another application?